# A different form of Taylor's Theorem

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In the electromagnetism textbook: "Modern Electrodynamics" by Andrew Zangwill, the author summarizes Taylor's theorem like so:

$ f(x) = f(a) + (x-a)\frac{df}{dx} |_{x = a} + \frac{1}{2!} (x-a)^2 \frac{d^2f}{d^2x} |_{x = a} + ...$

which seems normal. However, Zangwill continues by stating if $x \rightarrow (x + \epsilon)$ and $a \rightarrow x$ then an alternative form of the theorem is:

$ f(x + \epsilon) = f(x) + \epsilon\frac{df}{dx} + \frac{1}{2!} \epsilon^2\frac{d^2f}{d^2x}+ ...$

and then says that this form is equivalent to:

$ f(x + \epsilon) = [1 + \epsilon\frac{d}{dx} + \frac{1}{2!} (\epsilon\frac{d}{dx})^2 + ...]f(x) = e^{\epsilon\frac{d}{dx}}f(x)$

Is zangwill correct here? I have never seen an operator that looked like this before, and I'm pretty sure $\frac{d^2f}{d^2x} \neq (\frac{d}{dx})^2f$.

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{df}{dx} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dx} f = \left(\frac{d}{dx} \right)^2 \! f
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the author is doing is very formal. The Taylor expansion
$$
f(x+\epsilon) = f(x) + \epsilon f'(x) + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2f''(x) + \dots
$$
comes from writing $f(y) = f(x + (y - x))$. Setting $\epsilon := y-x$ gives us the above Taylor expansion.

For the second bit where the author writes
$$
f(x+\epsilon) = e^{\epsilon\frac{d}{dx}}f(x),
$$
we are considering $e^{\epsilon\frac{d}{dx}}$ as an operator and formally plugging in the argument $\epsilon\frac{d}{dx}$ into the definition of $e^x$:
$$
e^x = \sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{1}{n!}x^n.
$$
So it's not really very deep per se, it's just rewriting the Taylor expansion with a bit of shorthand.

For clarity, keep in mind that we make the following notational convention:
$$
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} = \underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}\circ\dots\circ\frac{d}{dx}}_\text{$n$ times}.
$$